# smarty code - access variables inside {php} tag

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I know we should avoid the {php} tag inside any template engine, still, let's assume that it's the only way on this case.

Considering this, I would like to request some help in order to grab smarty string for php consumption.

On this case, I would like to access $result.domain inside the srtstr php function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{foreach key=period item=regoption from=$result.regoptions}
{if $regoption.$domain}
{if $domain eq "transfer"}
{php}
   $domainName = $result.domain;
   $tld = strstr($domainName, '.');
{/php}

{if $tld eq '.gt'}
   <p>Something</p>
{else}
<option value="{$period}">{$period} {$LANG.orderyears} @ {$regoption.$domain}</option>
{/if}
{/if}
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Thanks in advance, 
MEM

Comment: From the looks of it, what you're trying to do can be accomplished without the `{php}` block, by simply looping through the `$results.regoptions` and doing the string replace before making the call to `$smarty->display()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [get_template_vars](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl), just make sure you use `$this` instead of `$smarty`

```
$this->get_template_vars('foo')
```

It would be a much better idea to rewrite what you are doing as a [smarty plugin though](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.tpl)

EDIT:

In your example you could do something like

```
$result = $this->get_template_vars('result');
$domainName = $result.domain;
```

Comment: and what would be foo on this case? I mean, I've tried: "$result.domain" and "result.domain" - no luck.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `$this->getTemplateVars(...)`?  [smarty docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl)

Answer (score 2):

`$this` doesn't work for us, we finally got it using `$GLOBALS` variable like this:

```
$variable= $GLOBALS['smarty']->getTemplateVars('variable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't {PHP} tags reference PHP Variables, not variables set through `$smarty->assign` ?

Perhaps you are trying to access something inside a {PHP} that you set through `$smarty->assign` ?

Try accessing the object as it is named in your .php file that calls `$smarty->dispay()`.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of smarty you have to use $template, instead of $this.

For example:

```
$template->get_template_vars('foo')
```